# Summing JSON values

Tags: json, postgresql, sum

Is there any way for me to read json data from a column and sum the values together based on their keys and arrange them. Example of the column is:

```
id_column | json_data
1         | {"A": 1, "C": 4, "D": -2}
2         | {"B": 3, "S": 0, "A": 2, "D": 0}
```

The end result i would like to get should look like this:

```
json_data
{"A": 3, "B": 3, "C": 4, "D": -2, "S": 0}
```

So the end result is actually a sum of the json data in each row and also the keys are arranged from A-Z.

Answer (score 2):

That would work as follows:

```
SELECT json_object_agg(key, val ORDER BY key)
FROM (SELECT t.key,
             sum(CAST(t.val AS bigint)) AS val
      FROM j
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each_text(j.json_data)
                            AS t(key, val)
      GROUP BY t.key
     ) AS q;

                 json_object_agg                  
--------------------------------------------------
 { "A" : 3, "B" : 3, "C" : 4, "D" : -2, "S" : 0 }
(1 row)
```

There is no order in `jsonb`, so I used `json` for the result.